# How to maintain page number in primefaces datatable after soriting the column?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my application am having the PrimeFaces data table with pagination, for each column we are providing the sort option.

My problem is currently user is in 5th page of the data table, once user sort any one of the column it brings back user from 5th to first page.
How can I maintain the page number after user sorts the column?

Comment: This is only possible when using the lazyDataModel of PrimeFaces **AND** implementing state logic that determines that if the sortfield/order changes, the new pages that is send to the lazyDataModel (1) is ignored and the previous is used AND it needs to send the current/new page to the client somehow. The reason that this is not implemented by default or is easily extendible is that it is **very** unintuitive behaviour. None of the applications I know of has this behaviour. Staying on page 5 has as much relation to the data becoming visible as going to page 1.

Comment: This question has been posted before but unfortunately I cannot find it and mark this one as a duplicate.